# Unable to detect my Home wifi after installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I recently installed LTS 16.04 as a dual boot with my windows 7. Post installation i am unable to connect to my home wifi. The broadcom driver is installed and working. The wifi connection works as expected on the Windows OS and on the ubuntu i am able to connect to the same home wifi if i tether it via my mobile phone. Also i am able to see my neighbours wifi in the list and a whole bunch of other networks except my home's network .Has anyone faced this issue.. any help would be great.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:f3500000-f3503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: f0:de:f1:f4:95:d7
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:31 memory:f3400000-f343ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlp3s0b1
       serial: 08:ed:b9:96:ef:1b
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=610.812 ip=192.168.43.121 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: Wait for Pilot6 or Chili555 to see this, and they will be glad to help you.

Comment: Did you try "connect to hidden wi-fi network"? under the wireless icon? Your router may not be broadcasting its ESSID.

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes, I will help you with a VTC!

Comment: If your home wifi is on a 2.4Ghz channel higher than 11, the broadcom modules don't allow it.  The channel.c file of the brcmsmac source code is full of regulatory checks.  I would report a bug against package linux at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu if you are in a country where channels higher than 11 are allowed and you cannot access them